# 1-digit MAC with error-catching properties?

Tags: mac, format-preserving

The well-known [Luhn check digit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) (used in credit-card numbers) is a public method to append a check digit on the right of a decimal number, so that any 1-digit alteration and any exchange of two (different) consecutive digits in the outcome will be caught with certainty.

Can we make a 1-digit Message Authentication Code (depending on a secret key) with the same (or slightly relaxed) error-catching properties, and providing some quantifiable degree of authentication? Say, some upper bound of the probability of forgery for an adversary able to obtain a MAC for $m$ random $d$-digit numbers other than the number targeted (assume it is chosen by the adversary).

---

Note 1 per [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/148058): The error-catching properties are bound to be a trade-off against a probability of forgery sizably better than 10%. That would be especially true if the adversary was allowed to get MACs for chosen rather than random messages.

Note 2: I now limit the question to the adversary obtaining the MAC for random messages (and only a fraction of these), for the reason in this [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/148092).

Comment: does this differ form increasing the mac size on providing some quantifiable degree of authentication?

Comment: Indeed, if the MAC always detects any single-digit alteration, then 9 chosen-message queries are trivially enough for a forgery. Also, even in the absence of chosen-message attacks, an attacker who can e.g. observe the MACs for the 9 consecutive messages $10n$ to $10n+8$ can trivially forge the MAC for $10n+9$.